# delegate error while trying to set it on previous view controller iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, viewcontroller

I have 2 `ViewController`s, ControllerA and ControllerB. ControllerB is pushed when button is clicked in ControllerA. I have helper Class `MyClass` with delegate, and in ControllerA I set dlegate and receive messages, now when I enter ControllerB I set delegate again and also receive messages. Now when I go back to ControllerA, I get error:

`[ViewControllerB retain]: message sent to deallocated instance`

Error occurs when I add `MyClass.delegate = self;` in ControllerA method `ViewDidAppear`. I need to restore delegate to previous Controller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the ViewDidAppear of ViewController A are you setting the delegate back to be ViewController A? Have you set the property type for the delegate to be strong? It should be weak/assign.

Comment: Delegate property is (nonatomic, weak). Property in AppDelegate of MyClass is strong, and I get that property in ControllerA and ControllerB. After I get property of MyClass, I set delegate to be self of current Controller.

Comment: It sounds like something you're doing inside MyClass. Why do you need a single instance of MyClass held in the app delegate? If only a single instance should be available are you implementing any methods to ensure it is a singleton class?

Comment: MyClass is class that is opening TCP socket connection, so I need constant connection trough my app. So I made delegate methods for data that come from socket. Delegate methods need to be implemented in both ControllerA and ControllerB. So I need to set delegate every time Controller changes.

Comment: This sounds like a good example of when to use a singleton class to ensure you only have one instance of the class open. This way you won't need to keep a reference to the object in your app delegate either. Check http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: Please post how you create MyClass and who holds reference to that object. This looks like you create one instance per controller and when you go back the second controller gets released, releasing the object of MyClass...

Comment: I create MyClass with init method, already implemented by system. Then I call method to open TCP socket. All that in AppDelegate. Then I create object of MyClass like this: MyClass *mc = appDelegate.myClassProperty; Then I set delegate of mc to be self of current ViewController.

Comment: Matt I can't use singleton class, because in one point I need to reconnect on different port, so I need to call init function one more time. But I don't thing problem is singleton. I have only 1 instance of MyClass object at the time. When I enter another controller, then I create another one and assign delegate to present view controller.

Comment: But who owns the MyClass object once you create it? Who holds the reference?